# Error phpMyAdmin en servidor NGINX

Tags: phpmyadmin, nginx, raspbian

Estoy haciendo una simulación sobre una máquina virtual Raspbian. Se trata de hacer un servidor NGINX.

Tengo todo instalado y me funciona todo salvo el gestor phpMyAdmin. Tengo comprobado que está instalado, pero que no me da respuesta a la hora de intentar acceder a él me da un error ***404 Not Found***:

[image: error phpmyadmin]

He probado algunas cosas que he mirado por Internet pero no me han servido. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres cuando dices que *tengo comprobado que está instalado*? ¿Lo has instalado descomprimiendo el paquete que te has descargado de su web o a través del gestor de paquetes de tu distribución?

Comment: Exacto, descargué el que ellos ofrecen y lo instalé, de echo creía que no había llegado a instalarlo por despiste y que por eso no me lo pillaba, pero al querer instalado me decía que ya hay un paquete con la misma versión instalada.

Comment: El paquete de Raspbian está preconfigurado para funcionar con el servidor Apache, pero no con NGINX, por lo que deberás hacer unos cambios en tu sitio por defecto. Por favor, [agrega a tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/321944/edit) más información de cómo lo has instalado, mientras iré redactando la respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El paquete de Debian/Raspbian está preconfigurado para funcionar con el servidor Apache porque incluye una directiva `Alias` que permite el acceso a la ruta `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` desde la URL `/phpmyadmin`.

Contenido de `/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf`:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Ese archivo de configuración no funciona con NGINX, por lo que tienes dos opciones:

**Primera opción:** agregar la directiva equivalente al `Alias` de Apache en `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` (dentro de `server { ... }`):

```
location /phpmyadmin/ {
    root /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
}
```

**Segunda opción:** crear un enlace simbólico desde el raíz del sitio web al lugar donde está instalado phpMyAdmin:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/
```

Esta última opción es la más sencilla de realizar. No es necesario teclear `sudo` si estás usando el usuario `root`.

Comment: creo que la primera opcion va a dar problemas con las solicitudes POST, tambien estas asumiendo que ya tiene configurado php en nginx

Comment: aqui dejo un [ejemplo](https://apuntes-snicoper.readthedocs.io/es/latest/linux/nginx/phpmyadmin_vhost.html) completando la configuracion de virtualhost que debe hacer para la configuracion de nginx

Comment: Acabo de solucionarlo, no ha sido literalmente con la información que me has dado, pero sí gracias a una idea que me has dado con tu comentario, que es mirar las ubicaciones de los archivos.
Utilicé el comando <pre>sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/</pre> pero luego me dicuenta de que la ubicación correcta no es html, como lo tengo configurado va a buscar phpmyadmin en la carpeta de mi sitioweb, por lo tanto, he movido el enlace que se ha creado a la carpeta de mi sitio web y fin. Luego buscando en el navegador con el nombre del sitio seguido de /phpmyadmin me ha funcionado.

Comment: Como no compartiste ningún detalle de tu configuración te expliqué la solución genérica. Me alegra saber que fue de ayuda para resolver tu problema.

Comment: Es cierto @JackNavaRow, la configuración de PHP hay que meterla también dentro del bloque `location`. Yo lo tengo en un archivo de configuración que incluyo allí donde lo necesito con un `include /etc/nginx/php.conf`. Obviamente la solución del enlace simbólico es la más socorrida, aunque yo uso la versión de phpMyAdmin descargada de la web oficial. Al instalar Percona Server for MySQL 8.0 hay algunas cosas "rotas" en las versiones antiguas (como la pestaña de usuarios y la autenticación).